# "The number of bars and waves"

Tags: fonts, truetype-fonts

In a number of documents describing TrueType fonts, especially Consolas (e.g., [[1]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/consolas), [[2]](http://www.lucasfonts.com/case-studies/calibri-consolas/), [[3]](https://fashionpoks614.weebly.com/blog/font-la-gioconda-mona), [[4]](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/code-new-roman), ...) I read

> the look of the text can be tuned to personal taste by varying the number of bars and waves

How do I vary the number of *bars* and *waves*? and, while we are at it, WHAT  this bar&wave stuff is all about?

Comment: Just a guess : This relates more to the creation of new variations of a font, in a font-creating utility. Bar may relate to the division between upper and lower halves of the letter, and wave may relate to the slope. In my opinion this funny phrase is being parroted without understanding, because bar and wave are not font terms, and is meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A longer quotation from your sources:

> OpenType features include hanging or lining numerals; slashed, dotted and normal zeros; and alternative shapes for a number of lowercase letters. The look of text can be tuned to personal taste by varying the number of bars and waves.

OpenType fonts can have [glyph substitution features](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/using-type-tools/opentype-features) that, when activated, change the appearance of various characters. Some of these features include [small capitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps), [text figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures), and [swash letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swash_(typography)), as well as “anything goes” style variants called *Character Variants* and *Stylistic Sets*. Activating these features requires OpenType-aware applications, such as recent versions of Microsoft Word and LibreOffice, and more sophisticated publishing and graphics software ([outdated partial list](https://www.typotheque.com/fonts/opentype_feature_support)).

In the case of Consolas, there are several *Stylistic Sets* within the font that change the shape of several letters:

[image: Consolas Style Sets]

Note that in SS04 the *f* and *r* add “bars” at their bases, while in SS05 and SS06 the *f*, *i*, *j*, *l*, and *r* add various types of “waviness”. I’m sure this is what the quotation is referring to.

Comment: So are *bars*  the same as *serifs*?

Comment: @Scott: In this case, yes, slab serifs.

Comment: Where did you find that last picture? I've been looking for a list of the stylistic sets available in Consolas.

Comment: After some testing in MS Word, it seems that 4, 5, and 6 are the only stylistic sets. Shame that ss6 can't be used for solely the lowercase L.

Answer (score 1):

I have researched the meaning of that phrase.
According to my sleuthing, it might have had some internal meaning
in the past for the Microsoft developers of Consolas, but that meaning is now lost.
This is all only guess-work that I cannot defend, but I have spent some time on it
and would like to share my thoughts.

My answer is based upon a forum discussion that I happened upon but can't find
any more. People in it were discussing the announcement of the upcoming Consolas
font, which had already contained this sentence. They were also asking about its
meaning, but there were no answers.

I would guess that the original announcement for Consolas was written by
a Microsoft developer who used internally these terms when creating the Consolas font.
Once the font was released, these terms were of no more use and were
discarded and forgotten.

This original announcement of the Consolas font has since been
copy-pasted to many other sources, with never an explanation for "bars" and "waves".
I haven't managed to find the very first mention of them.

The two terms of "bars" and "waves" are completely unknown in the world of fonts.
The Consolas font, or any other font, cannot be customized when used.
Wikipedia lists for [Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font)
the elements one can vary when drawing text with a font, which are the common
size, weight, slope, and some other parameters.
Nowhere does Wikipedia, or any of the sources it links to,
mention any "bars" or "waves".

If I really went out on a limb with a wild guess, the term "bar" might relate
to a character's [Baseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29)
and other bars such the Median.
"Wave" might relate to slope, but this is really stretching it.

You may see these various bars, important to any developer of fonts,
in this Wikipedia image :

[image]

We will probably never know what is the meaning of that phrase, unless the
original developers of Consolas come forward and explain it.
It will probably keep on being quoted everywhere, precisely because it
seems to mean something. But what ? Nobody knows.

Comment: "[…] any other font, cannot be customized when used" – So even if bars and waves exist as hidden features of the Consolas font, then "bars" are "bells" and "waves" are "whistles". [Bells and whistles](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bells+and+whistles).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I think that they were elements used in the font generator that was used to create Consolas. It might be an internal tool of Microsoft, because I never managed to locate any such tool.

Comment: *> any other font, cannot be customized when used* -- [not quite true these days](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/09/variable-fonts-arrive-in-firefox-62/) ([see also](https://medium.com/variable-fonts/https-medium-com-tiro-introducing-opentype-variable-fonts-12ba6cd2369)), though it maybe was in the early days of Consolas.